# How to set Fontfile From assets folder in ffmpeg (android studio)

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I want to set font file in ffmpegn from assets folder in android. Can someone suggest me how can i do that. Following is my drawtext command :- 
 drawtext=fontsize=60:fontfile=/system/fonts/DroidSans.ttf:fontcolor=green:text=Post:x=150:y=150

Comment: Here is a similar question, please check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925463/how-to-use-command-of-ffmpeg-on-android

Comment: Have u got any solution

Comment: how can access from Assets FFMPEG

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? Having the same issue where the fontfile is not being used to write the font, even though the path is pointing towards the assets folder.

Answer (score -1):

Write file by loading asset data as bytes

```
final filename = 'font.ttf';
var bytes = await rootBundle
    .load("packages/flutter_video_editor/assets/font/aller.ttf");

String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
final path = '$dir/$filename';

final buffer = bytes.buffer;
await File(path).writeAsBytes(
    buffer.asUint8List(bytes.offsetInBytes, bytes.lengthInBytes));

File file = File('$dir/$filename');

print('Loaded file ${file.path}');
_flutterFFmpegConfig.setFontDirectory(file.path, null);

return file.path;
```